# Create a Gantt-like, parallel bar chart for parallel thread timing visualization

Tags: charts, visualization

I need to create a chart which is sort of like what Chrome Inspector shows you to visualize all page-related requests on a timeline. Input data is a simple tuple:

```
(start_timestamp, end_timestamp, task_name)
```

Task are independent, so I'm not interested it Gantt-like "Y-goes-after-X" visualization.

My approach right now would be to hack a stacked horizontal bar chart (first bar in a stack would be transparent, to give the effect of tasks starting later than T equal 0).

I'm just wondering if there's something already made for this kind of visualization.

Any sane language will do, really.

Answer (score 7):

A JavaScript charting library with floating bar charts should be able to do what you want for flexible task timing. Some even have a UTC option so you could use that for your time stamp data, if that's how it is collected.

Here is a basic demo I made with [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com)'s JS chart library, with two tasks across months:

```js
var myConfig = {
        "type":"hbar",
        "title":{
            "text":"Timing Visualization"
        },
        "plot":{
            
        },
        "scale-x":{
          "values":["task1","task2"]
        },
        "scale-y":{
          "values":["Jan",
            "Feb",
            "Mar",
            "Apr",
            "May",
            "Jun",
            "Jul",
            "Aug",
            "Sept",
            "Oct"],
          "item":{
            "font-size":"6px"
          }
            },
        "series":[
            {
                "values":[10,1],
                "offset-values":[1,1],
                "text":"Microsoft",
                "background-color":"#2ABCF8"
            },
            {
                "values":[7,3],
                "offset-values":[2,2],
                "text":"Oracle",
                "background-color":"#15A7E3"
            },
            {
                "values":[6,10],
                "offset-values":[3,3],
                "text":"Dell",
                "background-color":"#0193CF"
            }
        ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 400, 
 width: 600 
});
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <!--Assets will be injected here on compile. Use the assets button above-->
  <script src= 'https://cdn.zingchart.com/2.1.2/zingchart.min.js'></script>
  <script> zingchart.MODULESDIR = 'https://cdn.zingchart.com/2.1.2/modules/';</script>
 
 <!--Inject End-->
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Full disclosure, I'm on the ZingChart team. Other JS libs available, but I'd be happy to answer any questions about how this demo was put together.